# Samba ad port 636 and 3269 disable tls 1.0 and 1.1

Tags: samba, tls

Samba ad port 636 and port 3269 by default enabled with tls 1.0 and tls 1.1.

Need help to disable tls 1.0 and tls 1.1, keep only 1.2

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by adding with smb.conf with the global section.

tls priority = NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.0:-VERS-TLS1.1

It worked for me.

reference link:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configuring_LDAP_over_SSL_(LDAPS)_on_a_Samba_AD_DC